# How can i access a private array with no getter Method from another class?

Tags: java, arrays, private

So guys im trying to access a private Array from another class. Is there a way to access said array without a get-Method for the array?

```
public class Entity {

 private int key;
 private int value;

 public Entity(int k, int v) {
  key = k;
  value = v;
 }

 public int getKey() {
  return key;
 }

 public int getValue() {
  return value;
 }

 public void setValue(int v) {
  value = v;
 }
 public void setKey(int k) // selbst geadded
 {
  key = k;
 }
}
```

Those are the elements that are contained in the array.

```
public class Relation {

 private Entity[] map;

 public Relation(int n) {
  map = new Entity[n]; // größe des neuen feldes
 }

 public int size() {
  return map.length;
 }

 public Entity extract(int i) {
  if (i >= map.length || i < 0 || map[i] != null) {
   return null;
  }


  int key = map[i].getKey();
  int value = map[i].getValue();
  map[i] = null;
  return new Entity(key, value);

 }


 public boolean into(Entity e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
   if (map[i] == null) {
    map[i] = e;
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 }
}
```

Relation is the Method im supposed to use. This class contains the private array which im trying to access.

```
public class Use {

 public static boolean substitute(Relation rel, Entity e) {
  if (rel.size() > 0) {
   rel.map[0] = e; // "map has private acccess in Relation"
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

 public static Relation eliminate(Relation rel, int k) {
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < rel.size(); i++) {
   if (map[i] != k) // // "cannot find symbol map"
   {
    counter++;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

And this is the class in which im trying to access the array. The methods here are not finished yet since im getting errors whenever im trying to access the `map` in the `Relation` class in any why since I cant figure it out.

Comment: Add a getter, when you declare a field as private - it is private and can be accessed only within the class...

Comment: You can access the array per reflections

Comment: What are reflections?

Answer (score 0):

To access fields, you need a [FieldInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
Type relationType = typeof(Relation);
FieldInfo fieldRelationMap = relationType.GetField("map",
     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

FieldInfo has a [GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) and a [SetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: There is the `java` tag under the question.

Comment: Aren't we lucky that the questioner wants an algorithm and knows how to translate this C# into Java!